# Day to year including leap years

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, calculator

I want to convert **days to years** including leap years but without using `new Date()`. I want to simply count 365 days with years.

So login I have tried:

- 365 days in a year.
- 366 days in leap years.
- Leap years comes every 4th year.
- `365*4 = 1460` days in 4 years but with leap year `+1` it becomes `1461` days in 4 years.

```js
var year = 1460/365; // 4 years
var leap = 1461/365; // 4 years including leap years.
console.log(year);  // result is 4 which is proper
console.log(leap);  // result is 4.002739726027397 but which should also be 4.
```

Comment: So is `731` equals to `2` or `2.something`?

Comment: You can just `Math.floor(leap)` if you want to make it 4, but why?

Comment: No, I would be 730 only in leap years didn't come. I will start from 4th years. 1 year 365, 2 years `365*2=730`, 3 years `365*3=1095`, 4 years `365*4=1460+1=1461` and 8 years `365*8=2920+2=2920` because 2 leap years.

Comment: @Tomasz Rup what if I have to count 100000000000000000 days in years including leap years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Get total number of years : `parseInt(days/ 365)`
- Now you have to handle number of leap years, so `parseInt((days/4)/365)`
- Now you will have to adjust this value in year count so subtract `leaps/365` to get their offset and subtract from years.
- Now you will have to handle surplus days. Say there are 4 leap years and 10 surplus days, but the calculation is based on 365. So you  actual surplus is `10-4` i.e. `surplusDays - leaps`
- Now calculate its value and add them to years and you have the value.

```js
function getYearsByDays(days) {
  var daysInYear = 365;
  var noOfLeaps = parseInt((days / 4) / daysInYear)
  var years = parseInt(days / daysInYear);
  var remainingDays = days % daysInYear;
  return (years - (noOfLeaps / daysInYear) + (remainingDays/ daysInYear))
}

console.log(getYearsByDays(365));
console.log(getYearsByDays(365 * 4 + 1));
console.log(getYearsByDays(10000));
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic might be a lot simpler if you think of it like this:
The rotation of the earth takes 365.2425 days, the fractional part adds up to roughly a day every 4 cycles that is why we add the extra day on leaps years.

Thus:
1 day = 1/365.2425 years

you can calculate the exact number of years using this constant